# ionic 4 Form control problem not showing value in input

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Ionic 4 not showing the value in input. I have 4 fields in my form. 2 is disabled. But i need to show some value in fix input. here is my code

```
<form [formGroup]="ionicForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()" novalidate>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-input  type="text" formControlName="username"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-input  type="text" formControlName="email"></ion-input>

    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-input placeholder="Phone" type="number" formControlName="number"></ion-input>
      <ion-icon name="call" slot="end" color="primary"></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
     <span class="error ion-padding" *ngIf="isSubmitted && errorControl.number.errors?.required">
      Please enter your 11 digit number
    </span>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label style="color: #1d808c">Select Operator</ion-label>
    <ion-select formControlName="operator">
      <ion-select-option value="Telenor">Telenor</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="Jazz">Jazz</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="Warid">Warid</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="Ufone">Ufone</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="Zong">Zong</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
     <span class="error ion-padding" *ngIf="isSubmitted && errorControl.operator.errors?.required">
      Please select operator
    </span>
</form>
</ion-card>

<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
  <ion-button expand="block" class="btn" fill="outline" type="submit" (click)="submitForm()">Save</ion-button>
</div>
```

As in form first 2 value i have disable it and showing some values but its showing error of `Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`

Here my .ts code

```
ngOnInit() {

    //Get user
  this.auth.getUserData().subscribe((data:any) => {
      console.log('home');
      console.log(data);
      this.data = data;

    this.ionicForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      number: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(11)]],
      operator: ['', [Validators.required]],
      username: [{value: this.data.username, disabled: true}], //here is problem
      email: [{value: this.data.email, disabled: true}],     

    })

  });


}
```

Its working fine if i am hardcoding value like `username: [{value: 'abc, disabled: true}]`

Its showing abc if i am hardcoding this but when i am passing value its not working

Comment: [(ngModel)]="data.name" or add form control and in ts code add formcontrolname.setValue(this.data["Name"]

Comment: @MostafaHarb cant ue ngModel in form ?

Comment: I think in current angular version it got deprecated, but you can set values to form group or you can attribute [value]="data.name" and will give the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You need To use ngModel to Bind Data in HTML

in .html file

```
<form [formGroup]="ionicForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()" novalidate>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-input  type="text" name="username" [(ngModel)]="data.username" formControlName="username" disabled></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-input  type="text"  name="email" [(ngModel)]="data.email" formControlName="email" disabled></ion-input>

    </ion-item>
  </form>
```

in .ts file

```
 data:any={
    username:'username',
    email:"email"
  }
```

Comment: You dont have to use ngModel when using reactive form